# Share iOs application demo with business partners

Tags: ios, flash, flash-builder

I'm working working on a project with international partners. I need to send my ios application's demo (via email), but I don't know how to make it. I can package it in ipa, but it can't be use on their iphone, because they aren't in my developer account. How can it be solved?

My app made with adobe flashbuilder 4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/). This website made for beta distributions. Register there, and send invitation to email of your friend. He will have to open the email in his device and follow instructions. After Your friend will register his device by installing profile, it will be possible for him to download and install applications from TestFlight site. You will have to add his device to certificate with which you will have to build the app.

Comment: Thank you! It is very useful, but could you help me, how can I share? I make a Distribution provisioning profile (and certificate), but in Ad-Hoc mode I need to choose the devices. I tried with my other phone (it wasn't added to te prov.prof.), but it can't work with Testflight (can't see the app)

Comment: Your distribution provisioning profile has to include devices that allowed to install the app